Navigation through Deep link from one app to another app in flutter
I'm using go_router for navigation in my flutter app and trying to open this app from another app through deep link. when i do so the app receives the deep link and app gets opened but the stack trace of the current app gets killed, but i want the current app to be at same widget and only pop up.Below given my routes code(App A, the one i'm trying to open).Is there any fix for this issue. Thanks in advance.
"
App A (routes.dart):
GoRoute(
 name: 'login',
 path: "/login/:value",
 builder: (context, state) {
 return SomePage();
 }),

App B :
final Uri appUrl =`your text`
Uri.parse(
'http://example.com/login/data' 
);
launchUrl(appUrl, webOnlyWindowName: '_blank');

"
Trying to navigate to one app from another app using deep link, while doing so the stack trace of app gets killed but i want to do nothing with that old stack it should be there
